# FromBluetoothAddressAsync throws 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10, uwp, background-task

I'm developing an app that connects ta a BLE beacon, for this I use the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher API. When I receive an advertisement I want to connect to the device to read the GATT characteristics.

So I start a BLEwatcher

```
    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;
    watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
    watcher.Stopped += OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;
    watcher.Start();
```

Then I try to access the device

```
private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var address = eventArgs.BluetoothAddress;

    BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
    Debug.WriteLine(device.Name + " - " + device.DeviceId);
    ....
```

This fails with (at FromBluetoothAddressAsync line)

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

The funny thing is: if I open the system's bluetooth devices window it works fine!

So when I open the bluetooth devices window and run the app the error is not thrown, when I close the bluetooth devices window it throws the error.

Note that it always throws this error in a background task.

Apparently it does work on build 10.0.10586.218.
I found this online from someone with the same issue:

> **LUMIA 950, Windows 10, 1511, 10.0.14332.1001**
>
> Exception thrown on FromIdAsync(): 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> **LUMIA 730, Windows 10, 1511, 10.0.10586.218**
>
> Exception thrown on FindAllAsync(): 'System.ArgumentException'
>
> **LUMIA 920, Windows 10, 1511, 10.0.10586.218**
>
> No Error!

Screenshots:
[image: When it fails]

[image: When it works]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't the BLE Windows APIs lovely and the nice (un)documented exceptions they give you?

You shouldn't use AdvertisementWatcher if you have the intent to pair to a device I guess. Instead use a DeviceInformation watcher with a specific selector for BLE-devices that contain both paired and non-paired devices. That will give a ready-to-use DeviceInformation object you can pair with.

The sample code for that can be seen at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing, scenario number 8.

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem**

This error is caused by calling `FromBluetoothAddressAsync` in a non-UI thread. Windows 10 requires user consent when an app tries to access a Bluetooth peripheral. When `FromBluetoothAddressAsync` is called, Windows tries to create a consent dialogue. Because this is not a UI thread, the consent dialogue cannot appear and an exception is thrown.

**Solution**

First, you should make the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` more specific to the peripheral that you're searching for. If you don't, then your app will see *every single Bluetooth LE device* and prompt for user consent on every one- a terrible user experience.

There are multiple ways to filter advertisements. You can do it manually in your `OnAdvertisementReceived` method using properties from `eventArgs` or you can set filters in the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` itself. For example, to find Bluetooth LE devices that have a heart rate monitor, do:

```
watcher.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Add(GattServiceUuids.HeartRate);
```

To make a call on a UI thread, you need to use a dispatcher. You can set up a dispatcher using the following code:

```
// Variable in your class
CoreDispatcher dispatcher;

// Init for your class
public MainPage() {
    ...
    // Init the dispatcher, this must be done on the main thread
    this.dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    ...
}
```

Then, when you receive an advertisement, you can do your own filtering then tell the dispatcher to connect to the Bluetooth LE device on the main thread.

```
private async void ConnectToBTDevice(BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs) {
    // This will cause a consent prompt if the user hasn't already consented
    var btDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
}

private bool Filter(BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs) {
    // Return true if the advertisement has the name we're looking for
    return eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName != null && eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName.Equals("Peripheral Name");
}

private void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs) {

    // Do our own filtering (for example)
    if(!this.Filter(eventArgs)) return;

    // Connect to the Bluetooth device in the UI (main) thread
    this.dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.ConnectToBTDevice(eventArgs));
}
```

Comment: The connecting issue was solved by the comment I marked as answer, by pairing first and then using FromIdAsync. However, I used part of this as well to fix it so thanks.